# Angular Material Select option control are overlapping on screen resize and are not in proper alignment with other control in large screen

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-material2

I am using angular material select and auto fill in side by side but both are not aligning in same way, means one up and other is down. And on screen resize they are overlapping each other.

This is how the code shows up as:
[image: Here]

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <md-input-container class="example-full-width">
        <input mdInput placeholder="Brand" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
        <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
            {{ state }}
        </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <md-select placeholder="Frequency start" class="example-full-width">
        <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
            {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <md-select placeholder="Frequency End" class="example-full-width">
        <md-option *ngFor="let FrequencyStartEndRange of FrequencyStartEndRanges" [value]="FrequencyStartEndRange.value">
            {{ FrequencyStartEndRange.viewValue }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, and work is being done to allow them to share the same styles (see [this PR](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/6488)).

Try adding this to your global styles:

```
.mat-select .mat-select-trigger {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```